# On rare occasions session attribute gets lost

Tags: java, session, servlets, cookies

I have an issue with an (so far) unreproducible error. It's definitely there, because there are 1-2 tickets about it every month.

There is a session attribute, which identifies the users' carts. However sometimes they receive an error, that only gets displayed if the cart id cannot be retrieved either from the session or the cookie.

What could cause such behaviour?

Comment: Are you using the `HttpSession` to set the session or are you using the `Cookie`?

Comment: My guess is that for whatever reason that person/user is losing their cookie/session.  It is quite common actually.  There are many reasons to lose cookie: people don't accept cookies in their browsers, the clear their history/cache, etc...  Sessions, the same thing happens, typically a session is managed by a cookie, so the same issues apply as above, but you also get timeout with sessions.  My guess is that people are leaving their browsers open for days at a time and then coming back and shopping again.  Just a guess though.

Comment: I wrote it up as a possible bug in tomcat, considering it hasn't been updated in quite a while. There's nothing in the code base that would cause such behaviour.